# RxJava2: Emit error only when all observables emitted error

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactivex

I have multiple observables doing network calls and I need to emit error from combiner observable only when all observables emitted error. If at least one observable completes then the result should be passed.

My current stream functions like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
.flatMap{networkObservable}
.reduce{combine result of all network observables to same list}
```

I could just do:

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
.flatMap{networkObservable.onErrorReturnItem(errorItem)}
.reduce{check if all items are error items and return error item otherwise combine result of 
all network observables to same list}
```

But I wanted to know if there's a better way to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if there is at least one item from any of the `networkObservable`s, errors should be ignored, right? In this case, you could detect the `onNext`s emitted, then in the error handler, suppress the error:

```java
Observable.using(
    () -> new AtomicBoolean(),
    hasItem -> Observable.fromIterable(list)
                         .flatMap(v -> networkObservable, true) // delay errors
                         .doOnNext(v -> {
                              if (!hasItem.get()) {
                                   hasItem.set(true);
                              }
                         })
                         .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
                              if (hasItem.get()) {
                                  return Observable.empty();
                              }
                              return Observable.error(error);
                         }),
    () -> { } // no need to clean up the AtomicBoolean
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution does look like it should work, but I try to avoid using .doOnNext operator in my streams also on first look it's pretty hard to understand comparing to reduce operator with error items. I'll keep searching for a better way to handle this case.